# SQL User History Table, Get last updated SPECIFIC FIELD

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, django, django-models

[image]

I have such a user_history table. Every time my users table is updated, records are dropped here as well. How can I get the date when my user updated his last salary information, that is, 2.01.2022 with SQL? I need to get the date it went from 200 to 300 (money field),so "2.01.2022"

I need to do this with DJANGO ORM but I couldn't even do more normal SQL query.

I tried to use sql lag,lead methods, but I could not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Two levels of window functions, one to find the changes and one to get the date change:

```
drop table #temp
select 1 as user_id,300 money,'03-01-2022' as update_date into #temp
union all
select 1 as user_id,300 money,'02-01-2022' as update_date
union all
select 1 as user_id,200 money,'01-01-2022' as update_date
union all
select 1 as user_id,200 money,'03-05-2022' as update_date

select user_id,money,update_date from 
(select t.*,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by cast(update_date as date)) as row_num from 
(select *,lag(money) over(order by cast(update_date as date)) prv_date from #temp ) t
where money<> prv_date) a
where a.row_num=1
```